# Removing Fparsec Pipes from a F# project

Tags: f#, fparsec

So i found a kind of abandonned open source project that uses fparsec to parse some graphql syntax. But I would need it in .net core and so I tried to port it. But the problem is, that it uses a `fparsec` library [`pipes`](http://rspeele.github.io/FParsec-Pipes/Intro.html)  that is not ported to .net core. So I wanted to fork the repo and remove the pipes library, so I can port the rest to .net core even tough I do not know F# or have any experience in `fparsec`.

This is the F# parser:
https://github.com/Lauchi/graphql-net/blob/master/GraphQL.Parser/Parsing/Parser.fs

I think I managed to translate some of the stuff back to fparsec, what I got so far is:

- `%[...]` is `choice [...]`
- `%% '#'` is `pchar '#'`
- `%% 'hello'` is `pstring 'hello'`
- `%% '[' -..-` is something like `pchar '[' >>.`

But by now you guys might have figured that I actually have no clue what I am doing because the syntax is very confusing to me. I understand what a parser and combinator is in theory and I have some understanding o functional programming and how i pass functions and parameters around but I just can not read the syntax and feel very lost.

Can anybody with some more experience give me some tips on how I can change this library back to normal fparsec code?

Comment: Why don't you port the pipes library to .NET core?

Comment: there is allready a PR on that, but the guy does not respond anymore :/

Comment: Well, the question you're asking is really too broad for Q&A. I don't see how anybody can help you short of just rewriting the parser for you.